# How should I configure my pool vacuum valves?

Tags: pool

I have an inground pool just moved into my house and there are no labels or diagrams.  Can someone tell me how to set the valves to use the in pool vacuum?

Right now there is no suction in the skimmers or vac, im assuming only the main drain

This is a pic of the suction side

Are the valves set correct and does anyone know what I need to adjust?
Right now there is no suction in the skimmers or vac[image]

Comment: Can you add some pictures? Back up and catch the entire pump set up how or where does the vac hose attach? And a close up of that pump label 'Hayward'

Comment: https://www.hayward-pool.com/shop/en/pools https://www.hayward-pool.com/shop/en/pools/support-center

Comment: George any luck? What is the pressure across your filter? Paper filters need to be cleaned at minimum spray them off (a cleaning solution and rinse will extend there life)   Sand filters require backwashing / rinse mode then filter mode, I mentioned paper because your housing is fairly tall, most sand filters I have worked with are short and squat compared to “fiber or paper” ghost are tall.

Answer (score 0):

Every pool is different.
You will need to figure out what the valves control by turning 1 off, then the other.
You may need to turn both off to direct all the intake to the pump to the port you hook the vacuum to or that would be my guess.

You can use a few drops of food coloring or crystal blue to see the flow into those ports (crystal blue is a clarifying agent that concentrated is like food coloring but will help make the water clear).

I have used this method as a young man when I was servicing pools (prior to completing my apprenticeship and a few on homes I purchased).

Once you figure out what the valves control deep end skimmer shallow end, bottom drain or whatever mark those valves with a sharpie or other permanent marker so you know and it clear for others that may be maintaining the pool later.

Comment: Thanks, I swear im in the twilight zone, I keep adjusting valves on the suction side and it doesnt seem to change anything, pool was working fine until I tried to figure out how to engage the vac port

Comment: George is your port a push in or plug in style? You may need to plug in and then close both valves to direct the flow to the port. After done open things back up. Normally a bottom intake can not be the only intake because that creates a suction strong enough to trap a swimmer on the bottom and has been the cause of drownings in the past.